# Is Google Fit API only read data at local?

Tags: android, google-fit

I have 2 Phones using a Gmail:
Phone 1 : install google fit app and sync data to web `[https://fit.google.com][1]`

Phone 2: not install google fit app, I using Google Fit Api read steps data.
But it can't return result.

my code:

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener { dataSet ->
                    val total = (if (dataSet.isEmpty)
                        0
                    else
                        dataSet.dataPoints[0].getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt()).toLong()
                    Log.i(TAG, "Total steps: " + total)
                    txtStep.setText(total.toString())
                }
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        object : OnFailureListener {
                            override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e)
                            }
                        })
```

---

Must i install google fit app on Phone 2?
Is Google Fit API only read data at local?

I had try use .`enableServerQueries`() but it still can't return data.

```
val endTime = cal.timeInMillis
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1)
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
        val startTime = cal.timeInMillis
        var readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .enableServerQueries()
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResult ->
                    var total =0
                    if (dataReadResult.buckets.size > 0) {
                            for (bucket in dataReadResult.buckets) {
                            val dataSets = bucket.dataSets
                            for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                                for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                                    for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                        total=total + dp.getValue(field).asInt()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (dataReadResult.dataSets.size > 0) {

                        for (dataSet in dataReadResult.dataSets) {
                            for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                                for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                                    total=total + dp.getValue(field).asInt()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    txtStep.setText(total.toString())
                }
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        object : OnFailureListener {
                            override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e)
                            }
                        })
```

I only can read data when i click `sync Google Fit Data` from `Setting`

Comment: I'm not familiar if you need to have Google fit App installed to get the data from other devices but you can check the documentation about [Work with the Fitness History](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_data). It stated, "creating a subscription before recording a data enables your app to sync with data from other devices, and also allows for the passive recording of data on the device." Also when querying, you have to add `.enableServerQueries()` in DataReadRequest. Hope this helps.

Comment: i had recording and data exist at https://fit.google.com. i had try use enableServerQueries but it still not return data.

Comment: @DT Having same issue. Did you get this working in the end?

Comment: @ciaranodc: No, I had managed Googlefit data by our Server.

Answer (score -1):

You can Subscribe to fitness data using **getRecordingClient** if you dont want to have the Google Fit App.

You can create multiple subscriptions for different data types or data sources in your app. Google Fit stores fitness data from active subscriptions even when your app is not running and restores these subscriptions when the system restarts.

The recorded data is available in the user's fitness history. If you also want to show the data in your app in real time, you need to use the Sensors API together with the Recording API. To record fitness data with session metadata, you can use the Sessions API.

> Subscribe to fitness data

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                }
            });
```

> DataReadRequest for Heart Rate

```
readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .bucketByTime(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();
```

> Retrieving data from History

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");

                    for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResponse.getBuckets()) {
                        Log.e("History", "Data returned for Data type: " + bucket.getDataSets());

                        List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            displayDataSet(dataSet);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                }
            });
```

> Displaying Data

```
private void displayDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.e("History", "Data point:");
            Log.e("History", "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
            Log.e("History", "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.e("History", "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Log.e("History", "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                        " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
            }
        }
    }
```